# How to count the numbers in each line from a file and write it to an output file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Counting the amount of lines in the file and counting the numbers in each line. Then writing it out to an output file

Code:

```
num_lines = 0
with open("Version2_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        num_lines += 1
print("Number of lines:")
print(num_lines)
```

From Text file:

```
1.0,1.123,1.123
1.0,1.123,1.123
1
```

So there is three lines in the text file and line 1 has 3 numbers, line 2 has 3 numbers and line 3 has 1.

Expected:

```
Number of Lines: 3
Numbers in Line 1: 3
Numbers in Line 2: 3
Numbers in Line 3: 1
```

Actual:

```
Number of lines: 3
```

Comment: @Prune Thank you, but I have posted several of my attempts that I have HONESTLY tried to solve and no one has responded to them, makes me feel as if I have no help here at all. The only help I have is when I ask small questions like these so I can learn from it and try to implement that into my bigger and complex code so yes posting these question and getting answers like the people in the bottom makes it so much easier and I am able to learn more. Thank you once again

Comment: There are no such attempts in this question.  Counting fields in a line, or finding floats in an input sequence, are already covered quite well on this site and elsewhere.  If you're not getting help from your previous postings, perhaps you need to examine why.  Using SO as a tutorial site is not appropriate.

Comment: @Prune to make things clear, what I meant was that I did not post this question multiple times but I have posted other questions that have to do with this question and no one has responded to them. Maybe it is too big of a code and looks unorganized so I asked this question and would you look at that, I have answers finally. If I wanted to be not honest about my work might as well pay someone to do my programs right? Would you like to be paid? I'll pay you $50-200 easily so I wouldn't have to have someone tell me to make an honest coding attempt. Anyways thank you once more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('Version2_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

print('Number of Lines: {}'.format(len(content)))
for i in range(len(content)):
    print('Numbers in Line {}: {}'.format(i, len(content[i].split(','))))
```

output:

```
Number of Lines: 3
Numbers in Line 0: 3
Numbers in Line 1: 3
Numbers in Line 2: 1
```

Comment: thanks! How do I change the line numbers so it can start at Line 1 instead of line 0?

Comment: Just replace `print('Numbers in Line {}: {}'.format(i, len(content[i].split(','))))` with `print('Numbers in Line {}: {}'.format(i+1, len(content[i].split(','))))`

Answer (score 0):

How about using `line.split(',')` to find the numbers in each line (assuming they are always separated by commas).

```
i = 0
with open("Version2_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        i += 1
        j = len(line.split(','))
        print('line', i, 'contains', j, 'numbers')
```